# How can I keep a folder on two computers in sync, without uploading to the cloud?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, sync, rsync, dropbox

I want to keep certain folders in sync between various computers. They are a mix of Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 machines.

I already know about services such as SpiderOak and Dropbox, but I want to keep these folders in sync without using third-party services or servers. Also, in SpiderOak, if you want to keep files in sync between multiple computers, you have to also keep a file uploaded to the SpiderOak servers which will eat up space.

I already have a server I use to host a personal webpage, and I never get anywhere near my limit on bandwidth. I was wondering if I could use this server a a fixed IP intermediary to sync between my two computers.

Comment: Are the machines on the same LAN or VPN?

Comment: Most of the time, yes--but not always. I think it would be good enough if it only worked over LAN.

Comment: You can use a program called Goodsync made by the folks who made Roboform it supports uploading to a remote server.

Answer (score 1):

Funny, I was *just* reading an [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/166424/how-to-sync-files-between-computers-without-storing-them-in-the-cloud/) on this.  You can read the article for yourself, Ill just highlight some of the suggestions.

- [BitTorrent Sync](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html)
- [AeroFS](https://aerofs.com/)
- [Cubby](https://www.cubby.com/)

Or roll your own server with

- [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/)
- [rsync](http://www.howtogeek.com/66348/how-to-setup-rsync-backups-on-linux-the-easy-way/)

Comment: I would add [ownCloud](http://www.owncloud.org) to the second list.